# Use of undefined constant DATE_RFC2822

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to send emails with the cakephp mail component.

This is working well but I got this notice in debug mode:

```
Notice (8): Use of undefined constant DATE_RFC2822 - assumed 'DATE_RFC2822' [CORE/cake/libs/controller/components/email.php, line 599]
```

It's pretty embarassing since emails have no "send date" when received.

I haven't modified anything in this component or in any file of the cakephp core (except the configuration files obviously)

Any idea?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this constant is used to format dates, cakephp mail component try to use it but it seems to be undefined, probably your version of PHP does not support it.

Comment: Yep, forcing my web hosting to use PHP 5.3 do the trick, thanks :)