# CakePHP email: undefined constant DATE_RFC2822. Solution using php 4?

Tags: email, cakephp

I'm trying to use the **Email** component. THe problem is that, after sending, I get a warning like **undefined constant DATE_RFC2822...**. Besides, the emails are received with a *12/31/1969 7:00 PM* date on them.

I've done some research and apparently ([Use of undefined constant DATE_RFC2822](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612313/cakephp-use-of-undefined-constant-date-rfc2822)) PHP 4 does not support it, which is the one currently in use in the web server I'm using.

The thing is that in the **Control Panel** of the webserver there's an option to change the **Global PHP version** to 5. However, there are many other websites hosted in the same server, so I'm afraid of changing that from 4 to 5 and screwing stuff up. **Is that a real risk?**

Or better yet, is there any way to fix the date issue without changing the PHP version? I don't see where I could manually add the correct time to the email that I'm sending with the **Email component**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not the answer you are looking for and you've probably heard it here already, but there really is no excuse to not be using PHP 5 in Q3 2011.

However, as it is just a constant, you could just define it yourself in your `bootstrap.php`:

```
define('DATE_RFC2822', date('D, j M Y H:i:s O')); // Sun, 14 Aug 2005 16:13:03 +0000
```

Comment: +1 If you wrap that in an `if (!defined('DATE_RFC2822'))` it's completely transparently portable.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that! What about my question about changing the PHP version from 4 to 5? Should that be fine? Or is there any risk that something that was working in PHP 4 won't work anymore in PHP 5?

Comment: You will be fine upgrading to PHP with Cake 1.3, I myself have 5.3.6 on my server. I'd recommend upgrading over this work around.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not so worried for the website I'm making, but for all the other websites that are hosted in the same server, which have a lot of PHP code as well... So if those websites are made using PHP 4, is it possible that something stops working properly if I upgrade to PHP 5? Or is it full backwards compatible?

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Sorry to bring this up again, but your solution suddently stopped working! Now the dates are wrong again, and I'm pretty sure I haven't changed any code that can affect this functionality... It's like the **define** is not working anymore, the email component doesn't use that constant

Comment: Actually it's using the constant, because if I remove your code I get the warning again, but the date is still wrong... It always shows 12/31/1969 7:00 PM

Comment: @Albert there's something wrong with the time on your server then, try `time()` as a second argument in the `date()`, can't see it making a difference though.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz the thing is that if I echo **date('D, j M Y H:i:s O')** I get **Tue, 2 Aug 2011 16:34:10 -0400**, which is the right time. However, the time in the emails is wrong. So either the _Email_ component is not reading the constant correctly, or the constant itself is not being updated when it's called...

Comment: @Dunhamzzz **CORRECTION:** The constant is updated correctly, I can echo it and shows the right time. So there's something wrong with the Email component reading it. It's for sure reading it, because if I remove the constant, then I get the warning, so I don't know what's going on here...

Comment: Again, I would start another question and post the code you use to send the email, as the original question has been answered.

Comment: OK, I really appreciate your help, but the answer given doesn't work for me. Anyways, I finally "fixed" my issue by doing **$this->Email->date = date('r');**. With this I get the right time in the emails all the time (at least for now). Thank you very much!